# How to give a button a custom shape in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I'm new to Java Swing, I searched a lot about this question on stackoverflow.com and other websites, but couldn't find a concrete answer, so I decided to ask it myself. I want to create a `JButton` of a custom shape - of the map of the USA. I have a png image with a transparent background. I know that

```
    usaButton.setOpaque(false);
    usaButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
```

will get rid of border of the button and remove the background color, but I want it to create a border around the map itself whenever I hover my mouse over it, not a rectangular border around the button. This is the map just for the reference:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3nIS.png]

Comment: Use two images instead, one with a border and one without then make use of the buttons rollover icon support see [`JButton#setRolloverEnabled`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setRolloverEnabled(boolean)), [`JButton#setRolloverIcon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setRolloverIcon(javax.swing.Icon)), [`JButton#setRolloverSelectedIcon `](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setRolloverSelectedIcon(javax.swing.Icon)) for more details

Comment: Out of curiosity I made a border that dynamically generates itself around the components rendered pixels. Its really slow and doesn't work well with smooth (semi transparent) edges. Do not recommend doing it that way :)